# Calculate overlap of two colliding objects?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**UPDATE:** I found [this enormously helpful article](http://www.playmycode.com/blog/2011/08/javascript-per-pixel-html5-canvas-image-collision-detection/) explaining canvas per-pixel collision detection.

I'm working on a collision system for a javascript game using HTML5 canvas. Each object has an image as a sprite and when a non-transparent pixel of any one object overlaps another, the collision code is triggered. But before anything else the objects need to be moved so that they are just touching each other and no longer triggering a collision. I need help calculating the overlap of any two objects in terms of x and y in order to move one accordingly. Here's what we know:

- The coordinates of the collision point relative to each object
- The positions of the objects (and therefore the distance between them)
- The width and height of the objects
- The velocity of the objects in the x and y directions (a vector)

Another note: the images for these objects are uneven shapes, no perfect circles, but the radius from the center to the collision point can be calculated.

**EDIT:** I haven't seen a lot of response, so I'll be more specific. In the image below, two objects are colliding. The overlap area is in red. How would you go about finding the lengths of the green lines?
[image]

Comment: Are you drawing these lines in Canvas also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm honestly clueless about HTML 5 and how you can make games in pure HTML 5. But you would also need to know a velocity (IE, their direction. This way you can send them backwards from where they came)

If it was in a standard programming language, one method would be to use a while loop (moving the sprite back until the collision == false). Another method would be a more complicated calculation of how far the intersection is and subtract individual x and y values so they are not collided.

EDIT:
Then the easiest way is like I said, to put the object thats moving in a while loop that moves it backwards 1 pixel in each axis until its collision tests false. Example:

```
    int x1 = 500; //x location on screen
    int y2 = 500; //y location

    public boolean fixOffSetX(Sprite s) {
         int x2 = s.getX();
         int y2 = s.getY();

         //not writing the whole thing
         //enter a while loop until its not colliding anymore

         while(collision is still true) {
            x--;  or x++; 

            //depending on direction 
            //(which is why you need to know velocity/direction of your sprites)
            //do the same for the Y axis. 
        }
    }


    //This method will return if the 2 sprites collided, you do this one
    public boolean collisionTest(Sprite s1, Sprite s2) {}
```

You should look at doing very basic collisions, since it is a VERY complicated part of programming

Comment: It's mostly javascript. Canvas is just for the display. Your second suggestion is exactly what I'm trying to do, I just don't have the mathematical skills for the offset calculation.

Comment: Good idea, thank you. I'll see if I can get something similar to work.

Comment: After a bit of testing, it seems like this works well for objects colliding head on, but doesn't work at all for objects moving in the same direction. I'm having them move the opposite of their original direction until there is no longer a collision. I suppose I could test both directions and choose the shorter distance, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Like I said, you need to know the direction of both sprites (their velocity). Have general collision detection method (puts a square/rectangle on both and sees if they intersect and returns true or false). On the method/function processing the collision, make sure to include both directions on the x axis and both directions on the y axis. As well as account the direction in the fixOffSetX() and fixOffSetY() functions/methods. There might be a better way, but this is pretty standard. Its either calculate where the sprite will end up and prevent a collision. Test a collision each frame and risk

Comment: and risk a collision overlap and then correct the offset of the x and y axis so that the sprites are no longer "touching". The problem could be your collision test function, or it could be that you only accounted for one direction/or none.

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I have, but testing both negative and positive directions for X and Y is quite expensive. I wonder if there is a way to calculate the correct offset direction using velocity/position, because the shortest offset path may not always be the correct one especially if the objects are moving at high speeds.

Comment: Collision detection is extremely expensive, and it costs more when you get to more advanced methods or higher accuracy. I'm still figuring more advanced methods, but this is the general method that is used in games.

There are variations that computationally are more efficient, but then again, you should probably create a working version of the most basic and then streamline it. (Thats what i'm currently doing).

Answer (score 0):

If this is still an issue, I've found information about the subject in an e-book called Foundation Game Design with HTML5 en Javascript. Here: [link to relevant pages](http://books.google.nl/books?id=QiHJr-TWmfMC&pg=PA476&lpg=PA476&dq=html5%20javascript%20overlapping%20figures&source=bl&ots=wlzAX1vMqP&sig=Th3X0WTWWnncPXk_ykE2TR9Rjhk&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=VHjyUeW1Eobbsgb1nICoAQ&ved=0CIMBEOgBMAg). Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: I actually found a brilliant article about this. I'll update the question.